# Accessing Data from JavaScript Object's Array Member Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a jQuery plugin for work which pulls in RSS feed data using Google's Feed API. Using this API, I'm saving all of the relevant RSS feed data into an object, then manipulating it through methods. I have a function which is supposed to render the RSS feed onto the webpage. Unfortunately, when I try to display the individual RSS feed entries, I get an error. Here's my relevant code:

```
var RSSFeed = function(feedTitle, feedUrl, options) {
/*
 * An object to encapsulate a Google Feed API request.
 */

// Variables
this.description = "";
this.entries = [];
this.feedUrl = feedUrl;
this.link = "";
this.title = feedTitle;
this.options = $.extend({
    ssl : true,
    limit : 4,
    key : null,
    feedTemplate : '<article class="rss-feed"><h2>{title}</h1><ul>{entries}</ul></article>',
    entryTemplate : '<li><h3><a href="{link}">{title}</a></h3><p>by: {author} @ {publishedDate}</p><p>{contentSnippet}</p></li>',
    outputMode : "json"
}, options || {});

this.sendFeedRequest = function() {
    /*
     * Makes the AJAX call to the provided requestUrl
     */

    var self = this;
    $.getJSON(this.encodeRequest(), function(data) {
        // Save the data in a temporary object
        var responseDataFeed = data.responseData.feed;

        // Now load the data into the RSSFeed object
        self.description = responseDataFeed.description;
        self.link = responseDataFeed.link;
        self.entries = responseDataFeed.entries;
    });
};

this.display = function(jQuerySelector) {
    /*
     * Displays the RSSFeed onto the webpage
     * Each RSSEntry will be displayed wrapped in the RSSFeed's template HTML
     * The template markup can be specified in the options
     */

    var self = this;
    console.log(self);
    console.log(self.entries);
};
};

$.rssObj = function(newTitle, newUrl, options) {
    return new RSSFeed(newTitle, newUrl, options);
};

// Code to call the jquery plugin, would normally be found in an index.html file
rss = $.rssObj("Gizmodo", "http://feeds.gawker.com/Gizmodo/full");
rss.sendFeedRequest();

rss.display($('div#feed'));
```

Obviously, my `display()` function isn't complete yet, but it serves as a good example. The first `console.log()` will write all of the relevant data to the console, including the `entries` array. However, when I try to log the `entries` array by itself, it's returning an empty array. Any idea why that is?

Comment: You did not include the code that _invokes_ `this.display()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that `display()` is called without waiting for the AJAX request to complete. So the request is still running while you already try to access `entries` - hence the empty array.

In order to solve this you could move the call to `display()` into the callback of `$.getJSON()`. You just have to add the required selector as a parameter:

```
this.sendFeedRequest = function(selector) {
    var self = this;
    $.getJSON(this.encodeRequest(), function(data) {
        var responseDataFeed = data.responseData.feed;
        ...
        self.entries = responseDataFeed.entries;
        self.display(selector);
    });
};
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to move `display()` into the callback, you could try something like this (untested!):

```
var RSSFeed = function(feedTitle, feedUrl, options) {
    ...
    this.loading = false;
    this.selector = null;

    this.sendFeedRequest = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.loading = true;
        $.getJSON(this.encodeRequest(), function(data) {
            ...
            self.loading = false;
            if (self.selector != null) {
                self.display(self.selector);
            }
        });
    };

    this.display = function(jQuerySelector) {
        var self = this;
        if (self.loading) {
            self.selector = jQuerySelector;
        }
        else {
            ...
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: That seems legit. One reason I have the display function not automatically called by sendFeedRequest is I wanted to give the developer control over when to display the information on the page (just in case they want to manipulate it first in some way). Any thoughts on how to wait for the getJSON() to finish before doing anything else?

Comment: If it's just about the `display` function, you could try the example above (edit). But if you want to perform other operations as well (which all have to wait for `getJSON()` to finish), you will have to use an other workaround. Perhaps an array in which you store the required operations - which then can be executed one after another in the `getJSON` callback? Just a spontaneous idea... ;)